# How to get default value of an item in Settings.bundle iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the default value that I've set of a item inside the Settings.bundle of iOS.

I can get the value that's set in the settings app and set it to a text label, like so:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let name = userDefaults.stringForKey("name_preference")
nameLabel.text = name
```

But I can't figure out how to get the default value that is set in the plist file (trying to get "Hello, World!") so I can add it to the label if there isn't a value set in the settings app. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: According to the screenshot the **key** is `Identifier` and the **value** is `name_preference`. Apple recommends to register all keys and values to their default values in code see [Accessing Preference Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

Comment: So I should remove the "default value" key's value and let it blank and then add the default value with Swift code? And how should I do that than? @vadian